# Android google map api v2 crash

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm trying to implement google map api v2 on Android application that i'm currently developing, for the java class i'm extending Fragment because i'm using navigation drawer.

The problem is: google map will work for the first time when you try to click on it from navigation drawer, but when you click on it again for the second time it will crash.

Here is java class:

```
public class FindUs_fragment extends Fragment{
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View layout= (View)inflater.inflate(R.layout.map_activity, container,false);

    return layout;
}
```

Here is xml file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <fragment

        xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
    map:cameraZoom="15"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is Manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.application.example"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.application.example.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <!-- The following two permissions are not required to use -->
    <!-- Google Maps Android API v2, but are recommended. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.application.example.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="api key" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Here is the logcat report:

```
01-21 16:19:28.884: E/AndroidRuntime(10557): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-21 16:19:28.884: E/AndroidRuntime(10557): Process: com.application.example, PID: 10557
01-21 16:19:28.884: E/AndroidRuntime(10557): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class fragment
01-21 16:19:28.884: E/AndroidRuntime(10557):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:713)
01-21 16:19:28.884: E/AndroidRuntime(10557):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
01-21 16:19:28.884: E/AndroidRuntime(10557):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
01-21 16:19:28.884: E/AndroidRuntime(10557):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
01-21 16:19:28.884: E/AndroidRuntime(10557):    at com.application.example.FindUs_fragment.onCreateView(FindUs_fragment.java:37)
01-21 16:19:28.884: E/AndroidRuntime(10557):    at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1700)
01-21 16:19:28.884: E/AndroidRuntime(10557):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:890)
01-21 16:19:28.884: E/AndroidRuntime(10557):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1062)
01-21 16:19:28.884: E/AndroidRuntime(10557):    at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:684)
01-21 16:19:28.884: E/AndroidRuntime(10557):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1447)
01-21 16:19:28.884: E/AndroidRuntime(10557):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:443)
01-21 16:19:28.884: E/AndroidRuntime(10557):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
01-21 16:19:28.884: E/AndroidRuntime(10557):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
01-21 16:19:28.884: E/AndroidRuntime(10557):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-21 16:19:28.884: E/AndroidRuntime(10557):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
01-21 16:19:28.884: E/AndroidRuntime(10557):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-21 16:19:28.884: E/AndroidRuntime(10557):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
01-21 16:19:28.884: E/AndroidRuntime(10557):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
01-21 16:19:28.884: E/AndroidRuntime(10557):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
01-21 16:19:28.884: E/AndroidRuntime(10557):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-21 16:19:28.884: E/AndroidRuntime(10557): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Binary XML file line #7: Duplicate id 0x7f050015, tag null, or parent id 0xffffffff with another fragment for com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment
01-21 16:19:28.884: E/AndroidRuntime(10557):    at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4790)
01-21 16:19:28.884: E/AndroidRuntime(10557):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:689)
```

May i know what is the problem that causing the app to crash?

Thank you for your time.

Update:

@Dimmerg: I'm attaching FindUs_fragment to a navigation drawer, the following is the code for navigation drawer activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private String[] drawerListViewItems;
    private ListView drawerListView;
    private DrawerLayout drawerlayout;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle actionbardrawertoggle;
    Fragment fragment = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        drawerListViewItems = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.drawer_item);
        drawerListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

        drawerListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.drawer_listview_item, drawerListViewItems));
        drawerlayout = (DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

        actionbardrawertoggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this,
                drawerlayout,
                R.drawable.ic_drawer, 
                R.string.drawer_open, 
                R.string.drawer_close
                );
        drawerlayout.setDrawerListener(actionbardrawertoggle);
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            // on first time display view for first nav item
            displayView(0);
        }
        drawerListView.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());



    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        actionbardrawertoggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        actionbardrawertoggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if(actionbardrawertoggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item))
        {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    private class DrawerItemClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener
    {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            displayView(position);
            //drawerlayout.closeDrawer(drawerListView);
        }

    }

    private void displayView(int position)
    {
        Fragment fragment = null;
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            fragment = new Home_fragment();
            break;

        case 1:
            fragment = new FindUs_fragment();
            break;   

        case 3:
            fragment = new Facebook_fragment();
            break;


        default:
            break;
        }

        if (fragment != null) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();

            // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
            drawerListView.setItemChecked(position, true);
            drawerListView.setSelection(position);
            setTitle(drawerListViewItems[position]);
            drawerlayout.closeDrawer(drawerListView);
        } else {
            // error in creating fragment
            Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
        }
    }
    }
```

Comment: what is the code at line no 37 in FindUs_fragment.java:37 ??

Comment: Please, post code where you attaching FindUS fragment to activity

Comment: you want map inside a fragment?

Comment: @NiravKamani Thanks for your reply, here is line 37: View layout= (View)inflater.inflate(R.layout.map_activity, container, false);

Comment: @Dimmerg Thanks for your reply, i have updated my question with requested code.

Comment: @Raghunandan Thanks for your reply, yes i want the map to be inside a fragment because i'm using a navigation drawer.

Answer (score 0):

you need to make google map null before you reload it..
it is work for me.

```
@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    SupportMapFragment f = (SupportMapFragment) getFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(id);
    if (f != null) {
        try {
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(f).commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    if (mMap != null) {
        List<Marker> temp = mMap.getMarkers();
        if (temp != null) {
            for (Marker marker : temp) {
                marker.remove();
                marker = null;
            }
        }
    }
    mMap = null;
    super.onDestroyView();

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, let me try this code snippet and i'll update you with progress.